# Proving $\int^{\infty}_0 \cos(tx)\left (\frac{\sin(t)}{t} \right )^n \, dt = 0$

Tags: integration, analysis, probability-theory, definite-integrals

I've been asked to prove that

$$ \int^\infty_0 \cos(tx)\left (\frac{\sin(t)}{t} \right )^n \, dt = 0, \space \forall x > n \geq 2.$$

My approach so far has been to use a theorem proved in class that, for a random variable $X$ with characteristic function $\phi(t)$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$ \mathbb{P}(a<X<b) + \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=a) + \mathbb{P}(X=b)}{2} = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{T}_{-T}\frac{e^{-ita}+e^{-itb}}{it}\phi(t)\,dt.$$

So, choosing $a = -b$, I get

$$\mathbb{P}(|X| \leq b) =  \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{T}_{-T}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\phi(t)\,dt$$

which makes it seem like I need to find a random variable that satisfies $\phi(t)$ and $\mathbb{P}(|X|<b)=0$... but I'm losing confidence in this approach, since it doesn't account for why $x > n \geq 2$ is required or incorporate the behavior of $\left(\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)^n$.

A solution using probability techniques would be preferable to pure analysis, but all help is appreciated.

Comment: What about "x" ?. Is it Real, Integer, Positive ?

Comment: Actually, the only restrictions seem to be $x\in\mathbb{R}^*$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$.

Comment: I think $x$ is presumed to be real and positive, while $n$ is a positive integer.  I do believe that $x>n$ is necessary, simply because of [counterexamples](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+inf+cos%282t%29+*+%28sin%28t%29%2Ft%29%5E3+dt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables such that $X_j$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. It is not difficult so show that the Fourier transform of $X_j$ equals

$$\Phi_{X_j}(t) := \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, t \cdot X_j} = \frac{\sin t}{t}.$$

Therefore, the Fourier transform of $Y := X_1+\ldots+X_n$ is given by

$$\Phi_Y(t) = \left( \frac{\sin t}{t} \right)^n.$$

Note that

$$\begin{align*} \int_0^{\infty} \cos(t  x) \cdot \left( \frac{\sin t}{t} \right)^n \, dt &= \text{Re} \left( \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\imath \, t \cdot x} \cdot \Phi_Y(t) \, dt \right). \end{align*}$$

Now use that the right-hand side is basically the (real part of the) inverse Fourier transform to prove the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

A complex analysis approach is to integrate the function $e^{ixz} \left(\frac{\sin z}{z} \right)^{n} $ around a contour that consists of the real axis and the large semicircle above it.

To show that the integral along the semicircle vanishes as the radius of the semicircle goes to $\infty$, we only need to show that $e^{ixz} \sin^{n}(z)$ is bounded in the the upper half-plane.

But this is clearly the case since if $x \ge n$, then $$e^{ixz} \sin^{n}(z) = e^{ixx} \left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} \right)^{n}= \frac{e^{ixz}}{(2i)^{n}} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}e^{ikz}e^{-i(n-k)z}$$ is a linear combination of exponential functions of the form $e^{iaz}$, where $a \ge 0$. And in the upper half-plane, the magnitude of $e^{iaz}, \ a \ge 0$, is less than or equal to $1$.

Therefore, since the singularity at the origin is removable,  we get $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ixt} \left(\frac{\sin t}{t} \right)^{n} \, dt =0,$$ which leads to the result if we equate the real parts on both sides of the equation.